# install storm on windows 10

Tags: java, python, apache

I'm new here and I've tried a lot of my own effort before calling you, guys.

I'm trying to install apache storm on windows 10.
I have installed ZooKeeper successfully, and set the Java_Home and Storm_Home.
Python is C:/Python27.
What I don't understand is those instructions:

PATH Add:

```
%STORM_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;
```

PATHEXT Add:

```
.PY
```

I've tried to add .PY to PATHTEXT and the &STORM_HOME%bin;... to the Path on System Variables but when I open the cmd and go to the Storm_Home, and run Storm nimbus, I get "storm is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Any help would be appreciated

TNX
Meron

Answer (score 2):

```
Download this storm setup from below link:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/iglqz73chkul1tu/storm-0.9.1-incubating-SNAPSHOT-12182013.zip

Extract that file to the location of your choice. i choose 'C:\'

**Configure Environment Variables**:

On Windows Storm requires the STORM_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables to be set, as well as some additions to the PATH variable:
```